# How to wrap the border of a table around rows that are not full?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I would like to create a table that consists of several cells in several rows, and when the amount of cells does not fit 100% to the table's size, the main table's border will not show as an exact square, but rather wrap itself around the content.

For example:

```
<table border = "2px">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

This is the current situation:

[image]

This is what I am aiming for:

[image]

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using tables.

Comment: you cant do this in a table, i think you cant do this at all.

Comment: One little tip, put your HTML inside the body tag, not after it.

Comment: Oops yes obviously I should have put the content inside the body ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible!

Through a heroic personal effort, I have reproduced your graphic using css only from your html.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ekoxl

[image]

It works like this:

```
table {
  display: block;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: #999 #333 #333 #999;
}
tr:nth-child(n+2) {
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}
tr:nth-child(n+2)::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: -3px;
  height:4px;
}
tr:nth-child(n+2)::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 4px;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
}

td {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid #666 1px;
  margin: 2px
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Only caveat I can see is that this is strictly CSS3.

Comment: Well yes, I had to do some intense gymnastics to get this to work.  I'm surprised it can work at all.  CSS3 is the price you must pay for jagged table rows I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by including the redundant cells and hiding them with the CSS `empty-cells` property.

**HTML**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table td {empty-cells:hide;border:3px double;}
```

Note the table itself is not given a border, but rather the cells themselves directly. Unfortunately, this will not work in combination with a `border-collapse:collapse;` declaration.

### See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/soboaz/YvB7C/)

---

**Edit**

If a second border is required, you can use the `double` value of the `border-style` property. Updated the CSS above and the fiddle to reflect this.

Comment: Interesting choice, however it will still remove the wanted outer border.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @JacobCohen Updated the answer with a second border. Not sure that's exactly what you meant, but it visually achieves a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that by table but can achieve it via div and css

still i have shown what td with little style can do

please check

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
td{border:2px solid black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border = "2px">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This basically removes the outer border.

It's not what I am aiming for.

Thanks for replying!